# changed doctype and the project is failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I was trying to debug some CSS issues that I have with my project and I read somewhere that chaging the `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` to `<!DOCTYPE html>` would solve some of the issues.

My Project is a old project and was created with out the solution. I just modify the .aspx and .cs files and moving those to the Server is producing the changes that I want.

Now after I changed the Doctype Iam getting the error that the textboxes on the page were not identified error. Some reason default.aspx and default.aspx.cs were not together anymore.

I changed it back to how it was previously. No luck. What is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried just saving your .aspx? Just curious if it could be the designer.cs class that needs to be updated.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the doctype declaration may have drastic effects, especially since it may move browsers to [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) or away from it. So just change it back, unless you are prepared to spending considerable time in analyzing and fixing the pages.

You are not telling any specifics, so it is impossible to say how the original problem (“some CSS issues”) should be dealt with. But it is generally best to start from checking the CSS code with the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).